# How to get to the properties of a generic class in a list?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic class like this:

```
public class StationProperty<T> : StationProperty
   {
      public StationProperty()
      {

      }

      public StationProperty(int id, T val, string desc = "")
      {
         Id = id;
         Desc = desc; 
         Value = val; 
      }

      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Desc { get; set; }
      public T Value { get; set; }
   }
```

Notice the inheritance, this I'll explain later but the abstract class looks like this:

```
 public interface StationProperty
   {

   }
```

As you can see nothing fancy - and no explicit properties.

Thanks to this mechanism I can pass around a List of these items like this:

```
var props = new List<StationProperty>();
props.Add(new StationProperty<bool>(39, true));
props.Add(new StationProperty<int>(41, 1));
```

So far this is all going smooth, but now I would expect to be able to do a :

```
Foreach(var prop in props)
{
     //prop.Id
     //prop.Desc
     //and most importantly prop.Value.GetType or prop.GetType
}
```

Instead these properties are missing:

[image]

If I manually add the properties to the abstract class then I can solve Id and Desc, but I would most likely need to add an object type for Value, and this would negate the reason for using generics in the first place.

So my question is, Can what I want be done? And where am I going wrong.

Comment: if `Id` and `Desc` are not generic why don't you add them to interface?

Comment: You're creating a `List<StationProperty>` where `StationProperty` is an empty interface. What properties exactly are you expecting to see?

Comment: Generics don't add properties to an interface, so your approach isn't going to work.  If you want to store different types in the same list you are going to have to use `object` for your value type. There are other approaches that are more complicated, but your question is too vague to point in the right direction for that. You'd be better off describing the problem you are trying to solve and then explain what is failing about this implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for code like below? 
You can always get the type but only read the value as 'object' when you are using the interface, the generic class can also get you the strongly typed value and allow you to set. You could also allow Value to be set via the interface and throw an exception if it is not the right type.

```
public class StationProperty<T> : StationProperty
{
    public StationProperty()
    {
    }

    public StationProperty(int id, T val, string desc = "")
    {
        Id = id;
        Desc = desc;
        Value = val;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }

    object StationProperty.Value
    {
        get { return Value; }
    }

    public Type ValueType
    {
        get { return typeof (T); }
    }
}

public interface StationProperty
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Desc { get; set; }
    object Value { get; }
    Type ValueType { get; }
}
```

Comment: The obvious downside is that you box each struct every time you access it via `object Value`

Comment: Just came back to say in practice it's working. As for performance, considering the execution context it's perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

For the `Id` and `Desc` properties the easiest way to get them, is to add them to the interface.

Or in you example it might even be better to use an (abstract) class instead of the interface and put the properties there.
With this approach you don't have to implement them in your generic class.

To get the Value property in the loop you need to use reflections:

`var val = prop.GetType().GetProperty("Value").GetValue(prop);`

This statement should do the trick.

Although, as @Steve Mitcham said in the comments, if you describe you original problem, maybe there is an even better solution.